# One Page Checkout Issue - Billing is not defined - onepage:1772

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, ce-1.7.0.2, billing

I have a problem with my one page checkout in my **Magento 1.7.0.2** store.  The store is not yet launched so all products are demo, but I can't seem to solve this issue.  At page load I get

> **ReferenceError: billing is not defined @ line 1772**

**It's inline javascript.  Here is the troublesome code below**:

```
billing.onSave = function(evt){
    new Ajax.Updater('onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load', 'http://purchaseblack.com/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/', {onSuccess: function() {
          this.nextStep(evt);
    }.bind(this), evalScripts:true});
}.bindAsEventListener(billing);

}
```

When I then use this page, nothing else related to finishing the checkout process works, and I get more, new errors.  *My question is this*:

**How do I define billing?**  **What file(s) do I need to edit to ensure that billing is defined properly and permanently?**

Hopefully, this is the root of the other errors, and I can move on to the next set of issues.

This is my first post and I am pretty new, so bear with me here. If there is any info I can provide to help you help me, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the inline javascript code that defines the billing variable. Compare the billing.phtml files in your current theme against the ones in:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
>
> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

You should see similar to below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! this worked for me