# Error customising checkout steps

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, javascript

I want to change the order of the Magento checkout steps. I have followed the instructions from [this](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/change-step-order-one-step-checkout-magento/) url, but I am seeing the following errors in the console.

1. `ReferenceError: billing is not defined`
2. `TypeError: $(...) is null`

What is the reason for this error?

This is the billing.phtml file (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml)

```
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li id="billing-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />
            <ul>
                <li class="fields"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getAddress()->getFirstname() ? $this->getAddress() : $this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->setForceUseCustomerRequiredAttributes(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?></li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Company')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:street1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address')) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address %s', $_i)) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street<?php echo $_i ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:vat_id"><?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="billing:vat_id" name="billing[vat_id]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('VAT Number')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="billing:telephone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:fax"><?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[fax]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Fax')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>" id="billing:fax" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>

        <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
        <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled() || $_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li class="fields">
                <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getQuote()->getCustomerDob())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGender())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxvat())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                </li>
        <?php endif ?>

                <li class="fields" id="register-customer-password">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:customer_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[customer_password]" id="billing:customer_password" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:confirm_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && $this->customerHasAddresses()):?>
                    <li class="control">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Save in address book')) ?>" id="billing:save_in_address_book" onchange="if(window.shipping) shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"<?php if ($this->getAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="checkbox" /><label for="billing:save_in_address_book"><?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?></label>
                    </li>
                <?php else:?>
                    <li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.onepage.billing.extra')?>
    <?php if ($this->canShip()): ?>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Ship to this address')) ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Ship to different address')) ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if (!$this->canShip()): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('payment'); ?>
    <div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue')) ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Loading next step...')) ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing the inline javascript code that defines the billing variable. Compare the billing.phtml files in your current theme against the ones in:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
>
> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

You should see similar to below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
//]]>
</script>
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4806/48355)

2. Replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: I have added the code. What change do I need to made?

Comment: What code are you added ? you just have to compare with of the `base/default` one like it explained in my answer

Comment: I haven't added any code. The above code is the the content in the phtml file.

Comment: The files in base/default and rwd/default is the same.

Comment: and you are using `rwd/default` theme

Comment: yes..now i am using rwd theme